# Ownership of an in direct model

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a user which own a house (several of users can own the house), the house can have several of furnitures.

CustomUser.json relation:

```
"houses": {
   "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
   "model": "House",
   "foreignKey": "houseId"
}
```

House.json relations:

```
"furnitures": {
   "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
   "model": "Furniture",
   "foreignKey": ""
},
"customUsers": {
   "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
   "model": "CustomUser",
   "foreignKey": ""
}
```

My ACL is simple and looks like this for both House and Furniture:

```
"acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "admin",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
]
```

Now, accessing houses for the users works fine, but the users won't get their furnitures listed since they belong to a house (the house is the owner). How do I fix this the easiest way possible? Best would be to somehow define that User owns furnitures through the house? The furnitures must belong to the house, though (since multiple users can have a house).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing my own role resolver made this quite flexible, in the role resolver I had to make logic to find the original parent and also make sure there were no dead relationships (since LB doesn't have support for cascade yet).

I recommend starting with this to get going:

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-and-using-roles.html

Answer (score 1):

So I got past this through another module called "loopback-component-access-groups" which lets you define groups. In this particular case I made the House-model a group which the users and furnitures have access to. A user can have different roles so I just set that the user (which have the role "member") can access the furnitures which are in the same group (house). This solution works for me, but I am not entirely sure if further objects inherits that they belong to a house if they are related to a furniture.

Comment: Also, with this module I had to make a "through" relation for a user. So I created an another model named "Team" which tells the relationship between a user and a house. This needs to exist so roles can be defined (the Team model contains the roles a user have for each house).